# i have a table which are having maticon buttons after clicking on button it should display 2 buttons at end of the table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

i have a table which are having mat-icon-buttons after clicking on button it should display 2 buttons at end of the table.
  if i click on button it chaining color  from primary to red color and now i want to 2 buttons for this button i mean after clicking button at the end after complication of table it should display buttons ( edit and save). i would like know how add that 2 buttons end of the table when we clicked mat-icon-button. 
please help me in these.
Thanks.

```html
<tr*ngFor="let data of database ">
<td>{{data.name}}</td>
<td>{{data.id}}</td>
<td>
  <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="data.isClicked = !data.isClicked"  [ngClass]="{'myClass': data.isClicked}">
 <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
  <tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your already implemented **data.isClicked** property to handle the visibility of the other buttons. If they should only be visible, if the first button is clicked just do it like this:

```
<tr*ngFor="let data of database ">
  <td>{{data.name}}</td>
  <td>{{data.id}}</td>
  <td>
    <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="data.isClicked = !data.isClicked"  [ngClass]="{'myClass': data.isClicked}">
      <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
  <td *ngIf="data.isClicked">
   <button>Edit<button>
   <button>Save<button>
  </td>
<tr>
```

---

**EDIT After clarification:**

Just combine your actions in a Click Mehtod then:

Your HTML File:

```
<tr*ngFor="let data of database ">
  <td>{{data.name}}</td>
  <td>{{data.id}}</td>
  <td>
    <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="clickEvent(data)"  [ngClass]="{'myClass': data.isClicked}">
      <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
<tr>

<div*ngIf="showButtons">
   <button>Edit<button>
   <button>Save<button>
</div>
```

And your .ts File:

```
showButtons: boolean = false;
clickEvent(data){
  data.isClicked = !data.isClicked;
  this.showButtons = !this.showButtons;
}
```

Comment: no actually  after clicking on remove_circle button this edit and save buttons should display in same page but not in table after completion of table.

Comment: ah I think I see what you want. Check my Edit in my Answer.